# Javascript member variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
function Class() {
    var self=this;
    self.searchfield=$('#search');
    self.resultbox=$('#searchresults');

    self.onSearchFieldChanged=function() {
        console.log("F: "+self.searchfield);
        console.log("R: "+self.resultbox);
    }
    self.searchfield.live("keyup",self.onSearchFieldChanged);
}
var INSTANCE=null;
Class.init=function() {
   INSTANCE=new Class();
}
$(document).bind("globalsloaded", Class.init);
```

As soon as I type something in #search input, the output on console is as following:

```
F: undefined
R: undefined
```

So why are those two variables undefined? They ARE in scope and should contain the corresponding jQuery objects.

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/nSRP4/.

Comment: It actually works, are you sure to call the snippet when the concerned dom elements are ready?

Comment: Did you forget `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Edited the post to show how initialization is actually done. `globalsloaded`is a custom event which is fired as soon as `device ready` is triggered (it's a phonegap app). So dom should be ready if the device is.

Comment: it sounds like your culprit is `self.searchfield=$('#search'); self.resultbox=$('#searchresults');` so double check your id's

Comment: Try to log them right after you instantiated the `CLASS` with `INSTANCE.onSearchFieldChanged()`. They can't really be `undefined`, otherwise you couldn't call the `live()` method on it

Comment: Provide a complete example rather than a snip; this is obviously an involved problem so all the components will be necessary to find the culprit.

Comment: The current behaviour implies the event is bound, and thus the code inside `Class` has been executed. In that case, `searchfield` *cannot* be `undefined` because `$` *never* returns that value. There must be something else happening - are you overwriting the variables at a later time? Could you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: genrally this problem appears when init is not done at `$(document).ready( function() { ... });` in this case html is still not loaded and the result of `$('#search')` is `null`

Comment: Works fine with this $(document).ready(Class.init);

Comment: Sorry guys. Didn't get a working example on JSFiddle. See my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days of work I found the Problem: JQueryMobile

What happens is:

1. `deviceready` event by phonegap
2. `domready` event
3. My init is called
4. JQM extracts the `input#search` element to reinsert it again, surrounded by some style divs
5. The div I saved in my init is no longer valid, as refers to the "old" dom element

Now I am doing my initialization in the `pageinit` event of JQM. No problems anymore.